# Excel file download dialog window using EPPLus not coming in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, epplus

In our web application we are using **EPPlus** for dynamic excel file creation.

Excel file is not downloading. No download dialog is coming

**Please see the below code snippet.**

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Student");

                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";

                int row = 2;

                foreach (var item in studentList)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = item.Id;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = item.Name;                       
                    row++;
                }
            //file download dialog is not coming.                    
            using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelName.xlsx");
                package.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(package.Stream);                    
            }
```

Anyone please help to achieve the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Excel file is not downloading

Comment: write the memory streams bytes to the response.outputstream

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're writing your bytes to a memory stream, but you're not doing anything with that memory stream. You're not providing a way for that stream to get back to the browser.

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Student");

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";

            int row = 2;

            foreach (var item in studentList)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = item.Id;
                worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = item.Name;                       
                row++;
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelName.xlsx");

            // note that we're not using a stream 
            // but rather the existing byte array.
            Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
```

Also, you should consider wrapping the creation of your ExcelPackage in a using statement, to ensure that the resources are properly disposed.